# Describe Function With Groupby Pandas (Python 3.5.1)

Tags: python, pandas

I'm wondering if I can use the describe function grouping by different values of a certain column?

For example, let's say I have the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
data = {'gender': ['male', 'female', 'female', 'male',' female'],
        'name': ['Jason', 'Molly', 'Tina', 'Jake', 'Amy'],
        'age': [42, 52, 36, 24, 73],
        'preTestScore': [4, 24, 31, 2, 3],
        'postTestScore': [25, 94, 57, 62, 70]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns = ['gender', 'name', 'age', 'preTestScore', 'postTestScore'])
```

Now if I use the describe function, I get the descriptive statistics for the whole data frame

```
df.describe()
    age preTestScore    postTestScore
count   5.000000    5.000000    5.000000
mean    45.400000   12.800000   61.600000
std     18.460769   13.663821   24.905823
min     24.000000   2.000000    25.000000
25%     36.000000   3.000000    57.000000
50%     42.000000   4.000000    62.000000
75%     52.000000   24.000000   70.000000
max     73.000000   31.000000   94.000000
```

If instead I wanted to group by gender and get the descriptive statistics by gender (so two separate outputs perhaps), how can I do so?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use groupby.describe:

```
df.groupby('gender').describe()
Out: 
                    age  postTestScore  preTestScore
gender                                              
female count   3.000000       3.000000      3.000000
       mean   53.666667      73.666667     19.333333
       std    18.556221      18.770544     14.571662
       min    36.000000      57.000000      3.000000
       25%    44.000000      63.500000     13.500000
       50%    52.000000      70.000000     24.000000
       75%    62.500000      82.000000     27.500000
       max    73.000000      94.000000     31.000000
male   count   2.000000       2.000000      2.000000
       mean   33.000000      43.500000      3.000000
       std    12.727922      26.162951      1.414214
       min    24.000000      25.000000      2.000000
       25%    28.500000      34.250000      2.500000
       50%    33.000000      43.500000      3.000000
       75%    37.500000      52.750000      3.500000
       max    42.000000      62.000000      4.000000
```

Comment: pandas is really impressive!

Comment: Thanks @ayhan! Is it possible to put multiple columns in the `groupby`?

Comment: @Vincent Sure. Instead of a string you can pass a list of strings: `df.groupby(['gender', 'age']).describe()`

Comment: For everyone coming here looking for fewer descriptive statistics: `df.groupby(['gender']).agg(['min','max','mean'])` is an alternative

Answer (score 1):

If you want two separate outputs, you could do the following:

```
df[df.gender == 'male'].describe()
df[df.gender == 'female'].describe()
```